# Is it possible to backup a GlassFish server 2.1.1 domain without stopping or suspending the server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, backup, jcaps

We are using JCAPS 6.3 with a build-in GlassFish 2.1.1 app server, we'd like to create a replication of the default domain (C:\JavaCAPS63\appserver\domains\domain1).

Is that possible to perform the backup by just copying everything inside "domain1" folder and pasting into a folder in another server?

We don't really want to stop/suspend the current server.

Thanks a lot if anyone would help.